# Alert Notifications from Asp.net to Android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

**`HOW I TRIED:`**

I have a scenario in which teacher would upload an assignment alert on the server with following thing:

1. Title
2. Description
3. Downloadable Links
4. created date
5. Deadline

and the student would get these detail on an Android. I have done this work (the communication between server and client side using WCF webservices). All the data is showing in the `ListView` on client Side which are uploaded on the server.

**`WHAT I WANT`**

1. A push notification of that alerts on a particular dates e.g (if the teacher uploads an alert on 14 April then the user on the client side would get a push notification on the same date).
2. DealLine push notification of that alert on a particular dates e.g (the user would get a dealline notification of that assignment on a particular deal line)

I have studied about the `GCM`. is the best way to send a push notification on an android device. But I don;t think that the `GCM` is the appropriate solution of my problem? or I just simply go for the `Android Notifications?`

Does anyone suggest me the how can I do this work? Any appropriate solution for this, or I would have to use any third party library for this work? any tutorial that similar with this problem? THanks in Advance.

Comment: GCM is a proper way to achieve this